# How to return a string without specified letters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to write a function that returns a string without the characters 'a' and 's'. For example, the string 'SAverageSsA' will be returned by the function 'verge'. And the string 'AsaAAs' will return an empty string. How can i do this?

```js
let testString = "AsSverage";

function removeAs(string) {}

removeAs(testString);
```

Comment: You don't need to write a function, just use `const string2 = testString.removeAll( /a|s/i, '' )`. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the string to an array and filter the elements.

```js
let testString = "AsSverage";

function removeAs(string) {
  return Array.from(string).filter((c)=>c!=='a'&&c!='A'&&c!='s'&&c!='S').join('')
}

console.log(removeAs(testString));
```

Comment: the output should not be an array, it should be a string

Comment: yes I updated the code to use `.join('')`